# Best case analysis, algorithm with nested for-loops

Tags: algorithm

In this particular algorithm, what is the bese case? Is there even one, in the sense that it is strictly better than the worst case? To me, it seems like the two would be the same.

```
sum = 0
for (i=1; i <= n; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j <= n; j++)
        sum++
```

Comment: Best case, worst case, in any case it's O(n^2)

Comment: That it would be the same?

Comment: I understand that they'd both be O(n^2). I don't understand how there could be an "optimal" context for this algorithm..

Comment: What do you think the time complexity of the two loops are individually?

Comment: There is not one.  Best case is the same as average is the same as worst.  With no escape possible all cases are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of a “best case” only applies when the algorithm's time complexity (or space complexity) can change depending on its input.  For example, a simple implementation of quicksort runs in O(n log n) time in the best case (when the pivots are the medians) but O(n^2) worst case (when the pivots are the minima or the maxima).

Your algorithm has only one input: n.  Its time complexity is O(n^2), regardless of n, so there's no particular “best case”.

Note that you can produce the same result in constant time:

```
sum = (n * n - n) / 2
```

Comment: ok that makes sense - is there anything I would have to show to show that best case = worst case?

Comment: Like it's pretty clear in this case that time complexity does not depend on the input - but is there a rigorous way of stating that?

Comment: Pedantic Caveat: Constant time assuming multiplication and division are constant time operations, which technically they aren't.

Comment: True, but then you also have to multiply the nested loop implementation's time complexity by the time complexity of `sum++`.

Comment: @AmazingVal If you prove that the time complexity of the algorithm is O(n^2), you will have proven that it only has one case.

Comment: @robmayoff: I think you mean `Θ(n^2)`, otherwise your statement doesn't really make a lot of sense

Comment: @robmayoff hmm, ok how would you "prove" it in this case? I guess I'm confused what constitutes a rigorous proof

Comment: This is covered in just about every algorithms textbook under the sun.  [As the help center says, “Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.”](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Anyway it sounds like this is a homework problem, so maybe you should ask your grader what she expects.